# TransactionTooLargeException nougat only

Tags: android

```
01-02 14:06:06.184 3742-5073/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 542516)
01-02 14:06:06.185 3742-5073/? E/ActivityManager: Exception thrown during bind of ProcessRecord{5cfa3c4 23962:}

 android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 542516 bytes
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:628)
  at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.bindApplication(ApplicationThreadNative.java:1183)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:8409)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:8526)
  at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:550)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3574)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
```

I suspect this is happening onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db). I had smaller database before and it worked fine. It is still working on the devices with previous android version.Any ideas?
My application have large database -320 tables at the moment. I have notice that if I commented out one of the providers in manifest android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size is a bit smaller... so looks like the problem is with content providers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to paste your onCreate code so your question is clearer and you get up-votes

Comment: "I suspect this is happening onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)" -- that is *very* unlikely.

Comment: Thank you . My problem is that is not even getting to the first activity. I have log in first line. I have as well sync service and sync account but if I comment this out is still not working. On android version 6 phone I can see logs that my database was created and that is going to first activity and app is working. The reason why I have suspect that problem was on creation database was first time it happen I just commented out one of the tables, doesn't matter which one and everything worked but this is not the the case anymore. App is freezing on first activity and looping error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you try to put more than 1mb of data in an Intent.

If your onCreate is doing anything like inserting initial data, you should consider doing it in several smaller batches (`applyBatch`) to avoid the issue. if you're trying to do something with images or other large data, your only options may be to reduce their size, or only pass a handle which allows you to access the file later

Comment: Thanks Nick. The problem is that exception happens in manifest. I have over 320 providers and for some reason I am getting this exception with parcel size over 500kb where on android 8 its even over 600kb exception.  The parcel size is reduce each time i commented out any of providers.  I have never heard of maximum size of providers to be decleared in manifest and did not have a issue in older version of Android.